# Value Relation returning geometries (points) contained in newly created feature (polygon) in QGIS as SELECTED

Tags: qgis, intersection, qgis-expression

I have a layer 'trees' containing 3 points.
The feature in creation (polygon) is in layer called 'zones'.
Two of the points are contained inside the future feature.
I'm using this expression in the value relation filter expression:

```
intersects($geometry,  @current_geometry)
```

[image]

This expression outputs the points inside the polygon, but by default they are not selected (checkbox).

Is there a way to have them selected by default?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Value Relation widget:

Use **Filter expression**

```
intersects($geometry, @current_geometry)
```

and
**Default value**
(check apply on update)

```
'{' + array_to_string(
 aggregate(
  layer:='trees',
  aggregate:='array_agg',
  expression:="fid",
  filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
 )
, ', ') + '}'
```